# How to match pattern with any number higher than 1

Tags: pattern-matching

I have text file with:

```
NH:i:1
NH:i:2
NH:i:3
NH:i:4
NH:i:9
NH:i:10
NH:i:11
NH:i:12
NH:i:1002
```

I would like to in unix one liner exclude lines if the number is different than 1 at the end. Potentially it can be number with any number of digits. I do not want to extract specifically NH:i:1 as I also have lines without this pattern that I want to keep. thank you i advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -E '(^|[^0-9])([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)$' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/9LCsAX):

```sh
s='NH:i:1
NH:i:2
NH:i:3
NH:i:4
NH:i:9
NH:i:10
NH:i:11
NH:i:12
NH:i:1002'
grep -E '(^|[^0-9])([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)$' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
NH:i:2
NH:i:3
NH:i:4
NH:i:9
NH:i:10
NH:i:11
NH:i:12
NH:i:1002
```